# Changing style of table cell after table has been drawn

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, html-table

I have a json object which contains a list of coordinates which represent a board and another pair of coordinates to represent another point (a turtle in my case).

I can render the board alright but I can't figure out how to render the turtle.

Do I need to use something like:

```
ang_element = angular.element(id=turtlePos.X + "," + turtlePos.Y ); // Get element by id and color background
```

Or is there a more "Angular" way?

Here is the table (Position 0,1 should have the css class "turtle"):

[image]

game-model-component.html:

```
<table *ngIf="gameModel">
  <tr *ngFor="let row of gameModel.board.boardTiles; let i = index">
    <td [attr.id]="i + ',' + y" [ngClass]="{'mine': column == 1, 'exit': column == 2}" *ngFor="let column of row; let y = index">({{i}},{{y}})</td>
  </tr>
</table
```

game-model-component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GameModel } from '../game-model';
import { GameService } from '../game.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-game-model',
  templateUrl: './game-model.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game-model.component.css']
})
export class GameModelComponent implements OnInit {

  gameModel: GameModel;
  constructor(private gameService: GameService) { }

  loadedGameModel(gameModel: Object) {
    console.log('Loaded GM');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(gameModel));
    this.gameModel = GameModel.fromJsonObj(gameModel['Result']);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Getting game data');
    this.getGame();
  }

  getGame(): void {
    this.gameService.getGame()
      .subscribe(gameModel => this.loadedGameModel(gameModel));
  }
}
```

game-model.component.css:

```
table, th , td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 50px;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.mine {
  background-color: red;
}
.exit {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

From this json:

```
{
  "Turtle": {
    "CurrentPosition": {
      "Direction": 0,
      "X": 0,
      "Y": 1
    }
  },
  "Board": {
    "BoardTiles": [
      [
        {
          "TileAssignment": 0
        },
        {
          "TileAssignment": 0
        },
        {
          "TileAssignment": 0
        },
        {
          "TileAssignment": 0
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "TileAssignment": 0
        },
        {
          "TileAssignment": 1
        },
        {
          "TileAssignment": 0
        },
        {
          "TileAssignment": 0
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "TileAssignment": 0
        },
        {
          "TileAssignment": 0
        },
        {
          "TileAssignment": 0
        },
        {
          "TileAssignment": 0
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "TileAssignment": 0
        },
        {
          "TileAssignment": 1
        },
        {
          "TileAssignment": 0
        },
        {
          "TileAssignment": 1
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "TileAssignment": 0
        },
        {
          "TileAssignment": 0
        },
        {
          "TileAssignment": 2
        },
        {
          "TileAssignment": 0
        }
      ]
    ],
    "Width": 5,
    "Height": 4
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have a turtle's coordinates and you need to place it on your table grid according to table's coordinates. Also, I assume you have a component called *turtle*.

I would try to draw it during your double `ngFor` iterations:

```
<table *ngIf="gameModel">
  <tr *ngFor="let row of gameModel.board.boardTiles; let i = index">
    <td [attr.id]="i + ',' + y" 
        [ngClass]="{'mine': column == 1, 'exit': column == 2}"   
        *ngFor="let column of row; let y = index">
      ({{i}},{{y}})

      <turtle *ngIf="turtlePos.X === i && urtlePos.Y === y"></turtle>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`turtle` component will be rendered on specified coordinates only

Answer (score 1):

Each component in angular have life cycle hook events. You can access DOM in ngAfterViewInit event. see https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit

Reference for all events: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    ng_element = angular.element(id=turtlePos.X + "," + turtlePos.Y ); 
    //other code
}
```